# OS X: capture events when NSApplication is *not* active

Tags: macos, events, event-handling, nsrunloop, nsapplication

How can an app capture events when it is not active? I'm finding that NSApplication doesn't dispatch events unless it's the currently active application (for instance, using `nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:`)

However, it must be possible to capture events while inactive. The Apple utility app Digital Color Meter, for example, is clearly getting mouse move events even when it's not active.